# PHP - skeleton for e-commerce system or CMS

Tags: php, mysql

After a few years I return back to PHP because of a project (it's an e-commerce system). I am looking for some good skeleton which would involved:

- database setup, database layer (MySQL)
- handling errors (not displaying errors to user's output - in the best way handling email via email)
- basic front-side and back-end side (administration)
- other stuffs would be a plus

Can you recommend me something? I need to developed an e-commerce system, but I don't want to start from total ground. 
Systems like OpenCart, Magneto etc. I wouldn't like to use for this.

Answer (score 1):

You want to build a E-Commerce project. Why do you invent a new wheel?

Building a good own E-Commerce software takes a lot of time especially the payment and right components. **Magento** has all you need for payments and for SEO and many more things also other software like **XTCommerce Veyton** or other shops can do it.

- Otherwise take a Framework like **Symfony2** and search for a **Shop Bundle**.
- You could take Typo3 and use a Shop Extension. There are many ways.

But building on your own is a lot of work.

I think you can discuss this now but in my opinion the best solution is to use a maintained system which can cover all or the most of your requirements.